# Domain Driven Design e Repository

Tags: ddd

Estamos refatorando um projeto onde inicialmente sua concepção fora apenas em CRUD, utilizando uma arquitetura muito simplória que até o momento funcionou. Estamos inciando algumas Rotinas, vimos que o que tínhamos não nos atenderia. Alguns membros da equipe iniciaram os estudos relacionados a Domain Driven Design e estamos aplicando tais práticas.

Foi decidido a utilização do Dapper extensions (insert e update), pois queremos ter o controle sobre as consultas SQL, visto que utilizamos SQLServer e RavenDB. Para o SQLServer queremos utilizar algumas ferramentas para a construção de Query dinamicamente.

Qual seria o melhor caminho para trabalhar com essas querys dinâmicas, digo, os parâmetros, classes, etc ?Visto que será necessário a utilização de DTO's.

Em qual do projetos ficarão as classes DTO's ? repository ? 
O que estamos pensando em fazer é uma boa prática e é válida ?

Comment: Sim, a pessoa estudou algo e aí tem que aplicar, mesmo que não tenha necessidade. Já pensou nisso? Bem poucos projetos precisam de DDD, e menos os que usarão de forma que traga mais benefício do que problema. Mas certamente todos envolvidos ficarão felizes de estarem na moda, tomara que não seja a única motivação. Parece que ninguém entender a parte do curso de DDD que não é para qualquer coisa. Não que eu esteja dizendo que não seja o caso específico, não tenho informação, estou só questionando. Me parece uma boa ideia fazer assim, mas não sou a melhor pessoa pra responder isso.

Comment: Se o Maniero não é a melhor pessoa pra responder só resta perguntar a deus